# How to determine if something was added to a struct?

Tags: c++, c, struct, sizeof

I have few small structs and one big struct that contains them:

```
struct A
{
...
};
struct B
{
...
};

struct AB
{
A a;
B b;
};
```

In different place at the code, I get an `AB` variable and do stuff with `AB.a` and `AB.b`. I want to make sure that if someone add a struct to `AB` he also updated the code that uses `AB`.

So my question is how can I check that?

I know that I can't trust `sizeof` and do something like:

```
 sizeof(AB)==sizeof(a)+sizeof(b)
```

I should mention that I don't really care what the small structs are, only how many are there in `AB`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

EDIT: if I assuming that A and B contains only primitives, what if I check:

```
offset(last member of B)+sizeof(last member of B)==sizeof(AB)
```

What do you think?

Comment: I suggest writing unit tests. They do what you want, they show that some modification broke the code.

Comment: I thought unit testing validates code correctness after compilation. I think the OP is after some tool (such as `make`) that forces re-compilation if some `#include`d files have been changed.

Comment: Have a look at [Boost.Fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/doc/html/), it can be used to automatically generate the `AB` struct and related code.

Comment: I can't use boost library in the code and the demand is to check that in running mode.

Comment: Also, what will I check in the unit test?

Comment: A substantial benefit of using the `struct` construct (over other constructs, such as discrete types) by many people, is precisely what you are asking about. The `struct` type can insulate legacy revisions of code from the need to add additional required variables.  i.e. you can add members to a struct that is defined globally, without forcing  change to the prototype of any function that includes it in its argument list.

Comment: You can't use the `offsetof() + sizeof() == sizeof()` test reliably.  It is fairly easy to devise situations where that will not give the correct answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, can you give an example when this won't work?

Comment: @or.nomore - Among other things, that approach is sensitive to environment.  meaning, with this approach, struct alignment issues can give different results from system to system, from compiler to compiler.  ***[Read more here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)***

Comment: `struct A { double d[2]; }; struct B { char c1; char c2; }; struct AB { struct A a; struct B b; };` — there's virtually guaranteed to be 6 bytes of padding after `b` in `struct AB`.

Comment: Put the files defining your structs into a version control system - e.g. `git` - then you have a history of modifications to the files, and can easily tell if the files have been modified, and by whom...

Comment: If you are using GCC, you can add the attribute __attribute__( ( packed ) ) to ensure that all have the correct size (to avoid padding). Then you could use sizeof without problems.

Comment: @CesarOrtiz - _...use sizeof without problems_.  There can still be ***[struct alignment issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)***

Comment: @CesarOrtiz - as I understood, using __attribute__( ( packed ) ) will reduce my performance which is really important here

Comment: @JonathanLeffler- what if I add a stub int field to the end of A and B ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found and currently in use is the following check:

```
if !(sizeof(A+B) + 3 >= sizeof(AB)){
  return error;
}
```

I have some relaxation assumption which makes this condition a solution for my question:

1. word size=4
2. All my small structs (i.e A and `B`) are big enough and contain a member with `size>=4`- which ensure eligning of 4 to the big struct
3. Struct `AB` contains only structs

In that case, if someone will add to `AB` a third struct, `C`, without changing this condition, he'll get an error (even if `sizeof(c)<3` because of the aligning). Which is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

With C++ a possible option would be to use templates and [Boost.Fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html).

We use  and an `boost::fusion::vector` as the aggregate class:

```
typename boost::fusion::vector<A,B> Aggregate;
```

Let's assume we have an operation which should be executed on all parts:

```
struct Operation {
    void operator()(A& a) { ... } // operation for A
    void operator()(B& b) { ... } // operation for B
};
```

Boost Fusion provides a function for simple iteration over all parts of a type container:

```
Aggregate x;
boost::fusion::for_each(x, Operation());
```

If you now extend the aggregate to `boost::fusion::vector<A,B,C>` you will get a compiler error when you do not provide an overload of `Operation::operator()` for type `C`.

---

Working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/at_c.hpp>

namespace bf = boost::fusion;

struct A { int a; };
struct B { float q; };

typedef bf::vector<A,B> MyClass;

struct IncrementOp {
    void operator()(A& x) const { x.a ++; }
    void operator()(B& x) const { x.q += 1.0f; }
};

int main() {
    MyClass c;
    bf::at_c<0>(c).a = 0;
    bf::at_c<1>(c).q = 4.2f;
    bf::for_each(c, IncrementOp());
    std::cout << bf::at_c<0>(c).a << std::endl;
    std::cout << bf::at_c<1>(c).q << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This *does not* answer your question directly, but illustrates how change to a `struct` can be managed without concern due to adding members over time.

(*Note, these ideas do NOT apply when REMOVING members*)

***A substantial benefit of using the*** `struct` construct (over using discrete types) is precisely what you are asking about: *ability to add members without breaking your code* The `struct` type can insulate legacy revisions of code from the need to add additional required variables.  That is, you can add members to a struct that is defined globally, without forcing  change to the prototype of any function that includes it in its argument list.

***For example***: given your scenario with the following structs:

(Note, I am using `typedef` so that the declarations will be shorter in argument list, and added real members)

***Here*** is your original scenario:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int a1;
    int a2;
}A;

typedef struct 
{
    int b1;
    int b2;

}B;

typedef struct   //small change for less text in prototypes
{
    A a;
    B b;
}AB;
```

***Here*** are two functions that use the struct AB

This one was written for use before any modifications to original AB:  (and does not currently need new member)

```
void func1(AB var_old)
{
    var_old.a.a1 = 3;
    var_old.a.a2 = 3;
    var_old.b.b1 = 4;
    var_old.b.b2 = 4;
    //Note:  if var_old.b.b3 is ever needed here, it is available without changing prototype
}
```

***sometime later*** a function is created (or modified) that requires a new variable

Add member to struct B:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int b1;
    int b2;
    int b3;

}B;
```

Use it here:

```
void func2(AB var_new)
{
     var_new.a.a2 = 10;//pre-existing member
     var_new.b.b3 = 4; //new member
}
```

The prototype argument list did not change, avoiding the need to edit every function that uses `AB`.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear enough, I meant that I want to force whoever added b3 to change func1 accordingly